# Three.js object positioning

Tags: javascript, three.js, positioning

I'm new to Three.js and wondering how exactly positioning works, any why is my icicle graph so scaterred.

[image: scattered icicle graph]

The parent starts at [0,0], which is directly in the center of the object (WHY?! it isn't in the TOP-LEFT corner). Al the other cfirst children in each level are also positioned at [0,parentLevelHeight], which is exactly same situation.

[X,Y] positions are calculated for 2D world, which fits just fine, but the centering thing happening in Three.js is unsolvable for me at the moment. Can, please, anybody explain me how does it work?

Thank you for your time and reply.

PS: AxisHelper
[image]

Comment: Where is your code? Add this line: `scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 1000 ) );`. Where the axes intersect is the origin `( 0, 0, 0 )`.

Comment: Directly through the middle of the first object, positioned [0,0]

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are in the wrong coordinate system. 0,0,0 is the center, not the top left. Your first child has to be (-(parent.width/2.0), 0, parentLevelHeight)

Comment: Is there any other coordinate system? Your solution is reasonable, but I'm calculating nodes positions in recursive function, which does not works well in this scenario.